# How to Trim elements before filling dropdownlist using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Here is my LINQ query using :

```
return dbContext.Books.Where(el => el.Name.Equals(name)).OrderBy(el => el.ID).ToList();
```

I get two values Value and Description from the list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBooks" runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="true">

ddlBooks.DataSource = EggController.getBooksList("Fiction"); 
ddlBooks.DataBind();
```

The below not working.

```
ddlBooks.Items.FindByValue(bookdtls.Book.TrimEnd()).Selected = true;
```

Issue: I think I need to trim the "Value" field as FindByValue is failing. Any help here? How to trim the below from ToList() ?

```
return dbContext.Books.Where(el => el.Name.Equals(name)).OrderBy(el => el.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trimming the datasource you could also use this approach to find the `ListItem`:

```
ListItem item = ddlBooks.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .First(item => item.Value.Trim() == bookdtls.Book.Trim());
item.Selected = true;
```

If it's possible that the book-name is not contained use `FirstOrDefault` and check for `null`.

But you should really trim the names *before* you insert them into the database.

> Unfortunately, SQL Server adds the values at right, which is giving an issue

sql-server doesn't add anything. Maybe you use the wrong data type, for example `char` instead of `varchar`/`mvarchar`. Then it's fixed-length. So if the text is `foo` but the column is `char(10)` you get 7 additional spaces. Then make it a `varchar`-column(if unicode use `nvarchar`) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I trim the values before entering into the database. Unfortunately, SQL Server adds the values at right, which is giving an issue during loading and selecting the field. I'm storing DataValueField in the table, not DataTextField, and selecting is tedious. I'll try this approach and get back to you if I need any additional help., thanks again.

Comment: @dotNETEngineer: sql-server doesn't add anything. Maybe you use the wrong data type, for example `char` instead of `varchar`/`mvarchar`. Then it's fixed-length. So if the text is `foo` but the column is `char(10)` you get 7 additional spaces.

Comment: That's a great tip, I always use nvarchar from the beginning and I realize why I'm struggling with trim issues. I will change all the datatypes for table design to Char instead of nvarchar. This is a great tip.

Also, thank you for the code, I tried, and it works awesome. You saved my time, I've been struggling since yesterday, and finally posted the question this morning and you helped me in no time. I appreciate it.

if (bookdtls.book != "") { ddlBooks.Items.Cast<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>().First(item => item.Value.TrimEnd() == bookdtls.Height.TrimEnd()).Selected = true; }

Comment: @dotNETEngineer: great that it worked. However, you got it wrong, `char` and `nchar` are fixed length, `varchar` and `nvarchar` can store any length. If you get empty spaces at the end that often indicates that you use a `char`/`nchar` column.

Comment: Thank you. That's true, I just checked the table design, and I see : nchar(100) which explains your point. I will probably convert them to nvarchar(100). There are several column names with nchar(500), creating trouble.Thanks and pardon my mistakes. Good learning today.